# Spectrum Sensing with USRP in GNU Radio

Tags: python, detection, gnuradio, spectrum

I have a real-time signal from USRP. I want to do spectrum sensing in GNU Radio. I just need to show the peak points of real signal in a figure. How can I do that?
Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried / researched yourself? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I have tried to write a code in embedded python block because I couldn't find any other solutions. I did set a threshold. I tried to identify point above threshold and also i tried to add tags on the peak points and print that plot. I have just learned to use GNU Radio that's why I am stuck. The code I tried to write:

Comment: Please edit your question rather than adding details as comments. That makes it easier for others to understand you question and help you. And please add your code in the question as well. It seems to have been truncated in the comment.